# strings become distorted when put into array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to take each word from a txt file and then place it into an array. My code has no problem taking each word from the file and saving it as a string. However when I try put the strings into an array and print it out and only prints out the last couple lines and it is all distorted.

Here is my code:

```
  typedef char * string;
  string strings[100];
  FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char line[256];

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
  {
    string tmp = strtok(line, " ,'.-");

    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
      strings[count]= tmp;
      tmp = strtok(NULL, " ,.'-;");
      count++;
    }
  }

  int c2 = 0;

  while(strings[c2] != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s, ", strings[c2]);
    c2++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the text from the file I am reading in:

```
There is a place where the sidewalk ends
And before the street begins,
And there the grass grows soft and white,
And there the sun burns crimson bright,
And there the moon-bird rests from his flight
To cool in the peppermint wind.
```

Comment: `typedef char * string` - **Never. Ever.**

Comment: Congratulations. You have a buffer overflow vulnerability.

Comment: All your pointers point into `line`, and that gets overwritten by each `fgets`.

Comment: You only allocated one string, and you did not initialise the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of obvious problems:

```
strings[count]= tmp;
```

This is just a pointer assignment. And tmp has the same value each time you make the assignment. You need to allocate a new string each time round the loop. And use strcpy to copy it.

Secondly your print loop assumes that the strings array is initialised with null pointers. It is not. You did not initialise it at all.